# What is the difference between "Bid welcome" and Welcome

Tags: american-english

I have recently watched Lord of the Rings and mouth of Sauron is saying " my master bids thee welcome. So I was wondering why just not simple "welcome".

Comment: It's an archaic / poetic usage. Similar to *We wish you a Merry Christmas* (or, somewhat "dated" today, *I wished him good morning*). But note that it wouldn't be valid to simply omit it from your cited text, because you still need a verb, and ***welcome*** there is a noun. It could be validly rephrased as *My master **welcomes** thee*, but that wouldn't have suited Tolkien's requirement for "stately, formal, archaic" phrasing so well. But please *don't* introduce usages like this into ordinary speech today (unless you're being deliberately facetious! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Or deliberately officious, obsequious, or archaic.  People who roleplay Tolkien characters love this kind of stuff.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It is deliberately archaic, stately, formal and odd and contains a hidden insult. It is not how people speak today. Not only is it over complex "bids you welcome" instead of "welcomes you", it uses the old first person singular objective form "thee".

[In the book, the mouth of Sauron doesn't say this but he does say "I have tokens I was bidden to show thee". Tolkien loves playing with language. His use of "thee" works on different levels. For most readers it is just rather old-fashioned. But if you know early English, then you know that "thou" was used rather like French uses "tu", and the use of "thee" is an insult when addressed to a Wizard or a King.]

Grammatically it is similar to "I wish you a good morning", and normally you wouldn't say that either.

Comment: I dunno. The entire trilogy and The Hobbit is fake Shakespearean. Your explanation makes it sound one-offish. His works are filled with the use of those pronouns. Thee and thou are both you, one as subject and the other as object. My Master bids Your Lordship welcome or some such greeting would have been more formal, I agree.

Comment: I see no fake Shakespeare in Tolkien. The Mouth of Sauron speaks quite differently from nearly all others. In fact the only other example I can find of "thou" is the Nazgûl "Thou fool, No living man may hinder me"  Use of "Thou" is typical of the upper class of Mordor.

Comment: Perhaps. But any use of thee and thou harkens back at least to Elizabethan times.

Answer (score 0):

Tolkien was Merton professor of English language and Literature at Oxford. There was nothing "fake" about his use of Shakespearian (i.e. Early Modern English). He did it to give the appearance of age to his story, while still being recent enough to be understood by contemporary readers.  I'm pretty sure he knew what he was doing.